# What is `git push origin master`? Help with git's refs, heads and remotes

Tags: git

I have a question about what `git push origin master` does:

- I know that `origin` is the remote (aka GitHub)
- `git push origin master` is the same as `git push origin master_on_my_machine:master_on_github`

I don't know if:

- `master_on_my_machine` is equal to `/refs/heads/master`
- `master_of_github` is equal to `/refs/remotes/origin/master`

If it's equal, should it be possible to do
`git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin/master`?

Finally, what I want to do is only type `git push` and `git pull` when:

- I'm on a master branch
- I want to push and pull from a my_test branch on github, only typing `git push` and `git pull`.

Comment: For a more complete answer, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch), which explains how to make a branch track a remote branch. Git pull -u didn't work for me, but git branch -u origin/branchname did.

Answer (score 38):

Git has two types of branches: `local` and `remote`. To use `git pull` and `git push` as you'd like, you have to tell your local branch (`my_test`) which remote branch it's tracking. In typical Git fashion this can be done in both the config file and with commands.

**Commands**

Make sure you're on your `master` branch with

1)`git checkout master`

then create the new branch with

2)`git branch --track my_test origin/my_test`

and check it out with

3)`git checkout my_test`.

You can then `push` and `pull` without specifying which local and remote.

However if you've already created the branch then you can use the `-u` switch to tell git's `push` and `pull` you'd like to use the specified local and remote branches from now on, like so:

```
git pull -u my_test origin/my_test
git push -u my_test origin/my_test
```

**Config**

The commands to setup remote branch tracking are fairly straight forward but I'm listing the config way as well as I find it easier if I'm setting up a bunch of tracking branches. Using your favourite editor open up your project's `.git/config` and add the following to the bottom.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "my_test"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/my_test
```

This specifies a remote called `origin`, in this case a GitHub style one, and then tells the branch `my_test` to use it as it's remote.

You can find something very similar to this in the config after running the commands above.

Some useful resources:

- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html
- http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html

Answer (score 14):

Or as a single command:

```
git push -u origin master:my_test
```

Pushes the commits from your local master branch to a (possibly new) remote branch `my_test` and sets up `master` to track `origin/my_test`.

Comment: This helped me to grasp the full picture on how it works. The previous answer obviously is good and detailed, but I still had confusion with 'origin' and 'master'.  Your answer helped me to see the connection which, in turn it helped to make @ghickman answer more sense.  Thanks.